# End_of_file/0 is not a function - error

Tags: prolog

Hi guys i have a question: I wrote a piece of code in prolog which has to take as input 2 numbers from a file calculate the maximum and output it in another file. Here is my code :

```
maximum(A,B,A):-A>B,!.
maximum(A,B,B):-B>A.

read2val:-
   see('C:\\Users\\Cristian\\Desktop\\in.txt'),
      read(X),
      read(Y),
      maximum(X,Y,M),
      tell('C:\\Users\\Cristian\\Desktop\\out.txt'),
         write('The max between '),write(X),write(' and '),write(Y),
         write(' is '),write(M),
      told,
   seen.
```

And now here it is my error:

```
    ERROR: C:\Users\Cristian\Desktop\in.txt:2:
    >/2: Arithmetic: `end_of_file/0' is not a function
```

and I also have an exception:

```
    Exception: (8) maximum(end_of_file, end_of_file, _G7760)
```

I want to mention that in my `in.txt` file I have the following input

```
    4. 5.
```

I would be grateful if you could explain me what i did wrong.

Comment: At the end of a file, `read(X)` succeeds with `X = end_of_file`. You need test for this first.

Comment: Which Prolog are you using? Either way, it seems that you are not opening the correct file (the file is empty?): both `read(X)` and `read(Y)` give you `end_of_file` which means you are at the end of the file.

Comment: @false But if you have a file with the atom `end_of_file` in it and you read it using `read/1`, how do you know it was part of the file and not the end of the file?

Comment: @Boris: In ISO there are some stream options and `at_end_of_stream/0` for this. But this is rarely used such that if you put `end_of_file.` into a Prolog text file, you can put any text thereafter (which is, I have to add, non-conforming behaviour).

Comment: @false what would be the conforming behaviour?

Comment: @Boris: In a Prolog text file (like `f.pl`), you can put the `end_of_file.` and most systems will stop reading that file. So you can put any text you like behind. It's de facto like a kind of comment.  Conforming behaviour would be to defined the fact `end_of_file.`

Comment: @false You mean define the fact `end_of_file.` at the end of every file? And I guess read any "user input" using lower-level primitives and then somehow escape any `end_of_file.` that would end up in the file I am reading using `read/1`?

Comment: "at end of every file"... ??? No, but in many systems this is *possible*. Try out compiling `end_of_file. f.` And see if `f` is defined or not.

Comment: @false OK, starting to get it. So the point is that _by design_ reading `end_of_file.` should stop reading further terms.

Comment: @Boris: I would not say "should".  That's the case in many systems since DEC10.